# Is there any api to read .epub file in windows phone 7 or windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to read .epub file ,please suggest code example how to do in my application.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://epubreader4wp.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Epub reader for WP](http://epubreaderwp.codeplex.com/)

[Another one](http://epubreader.codeplex.com/)